# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework - edit function did not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my model:

```
public class Auction
{
      [Key]
      [Required]
      public long Id { get; internal set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Title")]
      public string Title { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Description")]
      public string Description { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
      public string productName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Product Price")]
      public string productPrice { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Auction Start Time")]
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy MM, dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Auction End Time")]
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
      [Display(Name = "Auction Start Price")]
      public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Display(Name = "Auction Current Price")]
        public decimal? CurrentPrice { get; set; }

        }

    }
```

Here is my `DataContext` class:

```
public class AuctionsDataContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }

        static AuctionsDataContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AuctionsDataContext>());
        }
 }
```

Here is my View :

```
@model Mohn.Models.Auction

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Auction</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.productName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.productPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here is my Edit part that does not worked in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Auction auction = db.Auctions.Find(id);

    if (auction == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(auction);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description,productName,productPrice,StartTime,EndTime,StartPrice,CurrentPrice")] Auction auction)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(auction).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(auction);
}
```

The problem is, when I pass my `Auction id` in the URL, then it will retrieve data to the view except start time.  And I cannot submit the details, it will cause an exception.

Start time will not display on my view,

I am showing a screenshot here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyj6.png)

Even if I submit the start date with given details on my View, it will throw an exception

The screenshot shows it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvDb1.png)

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted

Please help me to solve this, and I am new to Asp.net MVC 5, Entity Framework, I want to know what exactly happen...

Thanks your attention....and help..:)

I guess the problem is in the ID...when I debug the program it is passed 0 to the controller...How to change this?...

Comment: db.Entry(auction).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges(); - This is where, The controller focus me to look

Comment: pls help me to solve this

Comment: Can you put breakpoint in the Edit(POST) method and see if the Id is properly set for the 'auction' object ?

Comment: Try using `DisplayFormat` attribute for `StartTime` the same as for  `EndTime` (which seem to be working).

Comment: @Boney - I will check and see......

Comment: @Ivan Stoev - I will check and see

Comment: @Boney - Yeh but In my database I was deleted my 1st Id and 2nd Id, But I am currently calling 3rd auction id

Comment: 3rd ID already saved in my database

Comment: @Ivan - I am using DisplayFormat for both, Do you mean to change into different date type. is it?

Comment: I think you need to first attach auction to the context and then change its state

Comment: @Kris - I am sorry, I am new to asp.net mvc, Could u please explain little bit more, in order to understand. thank you

Comment: db.Auctios.Attach(auction); you need to add this first, after that db.Entry(aution).State

Comment: @Kris - thank you very much, I will try on that and tell you..

Comment: @Kris - I was tried, but it is the same....Again throws the same exception

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted " focusing on "db.SaveChanges();"..

Comment: @Kris - this is the error - same

Comment: Okay do one thing instead attach add object and change its state

Comment: @Kris - How do I change...? if you don't mind, could you please tell me..

Comment: Will tell you first put a break point in Edit method and see if all the properties are binded from view in aution ?

Comment: I think you are right...If i comment this, //db.Entry(auction).State = EntityState.Modified; its actually redirect to the home page without updating...

Comment: @kris - and again kris - I am new to asp.net mvc........ I am sorry keep asking this......:)...if you don't mind, please...

Comment: No problem. Check if aution has all the values in the quick watch. I am thinking maybe Id is not binding

Comment: But the id is automatically generated when I create an auction...

Comment: But for some cases, I was deleted 1st ID and the 2nd ID, so when I look into my database, now currently saved 3rd ID and 4th ID with details...

Comment: I am saying when you edit it, the view has to send it back from hidden field, check if it's passing back by putting a break point in edit httppost method

Comment: Again I looked into my database, all the data inserted starting on 3rd ID, and I checked with the controller and the database - All details are mentioned there...@Kris......

Comment: @Kris - i will try that also...

Comment: @Kris - How do i put a break point in the controller or view? Do i need to check Controller? I am not clear

Comment: In the controller put a break in the edit method

Comment: In the Conner break point right? I took it..

Comment: @Kris - It did not appeared anything

Comment: What did not appear ?

Comment: When I move my cursor to the red color circle (break point) , it appears this - "Location : AuctionContoller.cs, line 117 character 9 (Mohn.Controllers.AuctionContoller.Edit(Mohn.Models.Auction)')"

Comment: nothing else appear there...@Kris

Comment: Check my answer I think it will work

Comment: Thank you @Kris for helping me,...I am trying now and tell you...what exactly happen...

Comment: The format string for `StartTime` needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format - as you have used for `EndTime`)

Comment: Problem solved - thanks to Kris (Removed internal from my model class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove internal for setter method id property. Due to internal model binder was unable to set value to it

```
      [Key]
      [Required]
      public long Id { get; internal set; }
```

Change it to

```
      [Key]
      [Required]
      public long Id { get;  set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your **Start Time** *format annotation* is **"{0:yyyy MM, dd}"** that seems **"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"** is true. after that because of your **[DataType(DataType.Currency)]** annotation and problem to transfer this field data, this exception has occured.

Comment: Don't mention it.first of all change Start Time format annotation attribute to {0:yyyy-MM-dd} and retry.

Comment: it is worked @Majid Parvin.. Thank you very much... But here is the problem - When i submit my form, id not passed to my controller.....

Comment: just for find your problem remove **[Bind(Include =...** and try again.

Comment: and remove **@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)**

Comment: I was tried, I used "Kris" answer, He removed [Bind(include segment, So I tried...but the same exception appeared again and again....This link ,i pick a screenshot from my debug results, here, go to this [link](https://ibb.co/djcYd5)

Comment: I tried that one also,...and I put some Text filed...and tried....no...it didn't worked...

Comment: and it says "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions." ... There is a link - [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540)   - but I did not understand if you know please let me know..